# ckEditor autogrow usability

Tags: ckeditor, usability

I am using [CKeditor](http://ckeditor.com/) with autogrow plugin. But there is a problem when I am working  with large text. I want to apply some style. So I need to scroll to the top of the page, click on the button and then scroll back to the bottom. This is very inconvenient.

Is there some plugin which can help to improve usability is such situations? Or I need to write it by myself?

Answer (score 0):

I would limit the growth size to a maximum value with something like `autoGrow_maxHeight : 800` - or whatever size works for you. I very much prefer the ckeditor content scrolling instead of the page scrolling.

Another option would be to separate the toolbar in a fixed element to make sure it always stays in sight. See http://nightly.ckeditor.com/7595/_samples/sharedspaces.html for an example; there is an editor there where the toolbar is statically visible and the editable area is apart from the toolbar.